# set up cuda 5.0 on centos 6.2

Tags: cuda, centos, installation

I want to set up cuda 5.0 on centos 6.2.It is failed, the error is below:

1. Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running
      kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files
      for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat
      Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the 'kernel-source' or
      'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source
      files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the
      '--kernel-source-path' command line option.

I had alread do the command "yum install kernel-devel.x86_64" successfully,but I do cuda_5.0.24_linux_64_rhel6.x.run, I got failed.

1. then I do "cuda_5.0.24_linux_64_rhel6.x.run --kernel-source-path='/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64', I got unknown option 'kernel-source-name', and I was failed too.

Comment: Make sure the booting kernel and the installed source are matched. In many cases, maybe you are booting the system in the Xen kernel while the kernel source is not Xen-enabled.

Comment: How can I know it?My centos is set up by ISO, where the source should be set up?

Comment: I do the command uname -r, I got 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64,and I do "cuda_5.0.24_linux_64_rhel6.x.run --kernel-source-path='/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64'", means the booting kernel and the installed source are not matched?

Comment: OK. The problem is not Xen but it is the mismatch. I can find kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm in my CentOs 6.2 iso. Install this rpm to resolve the mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Download the following RPMs:

> http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm
>   http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-debug-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm

and install them using:

```
rpm -iv kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm kernel-debug-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Find any other missing rpm at [here](http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/)

Comment: Another question:why can't we the rpm package in the ISO.

Comment: Do you mean why the packages are not included in your CentOS ISO?

Comment: Sorry,I lost word "use" in the last question?I mean I found your provide two packages in my CentOS ISO,why I could not you them and I should download them from the website.And another question is what the package named kernel-debug-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm use for?

Comment: I met another question today, I have two options while starting the OS which is 2.6.32-220.e16.x86_64.debug and 2.6.32-220.e16.x86_64 , the OS can't start for 2.6.32-220.e16.x86_64 ,while I selected 2.6.32-220.e16.x86_64.debug ,the original cuda software is not available, so I setted up the software of cuda, I got the same failed message of beginning?

Comment: I wonder why the question is closed?